# Windows Update trying to install update that's already installed

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v21h1

Windows Update is constantly trying to a install a windows update that's already installed. To be specific it's September 1st [2021-08 Cumulative Update Preview KB5005101](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-1-2021-kb5005101-os-builds-19041-1202-19042-1202-and-19043-1202-preview-82a50f27-a56f-4212-96ce-1554e8058dc1) or September 14 [2021-09 Cumulative Update KB5005565](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-14-2021-kb5005565-os-builds-19041-1237-19042-1237-and-19043-1237-292cf8ed-f97b-4cd8-9883-32b71e3e6b44) I'm using Windows 10 21H1.

This seems to be related to [my previous problem](https://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/185631-cumulative-updates-windows-10-wont-install.html) with Windows Update from the same month.

As you can imagine, if it's going to keep trying to install updates that are already installed, then Windows Update might be stuck in the past and might not ever install any future updates, as it'll think the previous ones weren't installed as a prerequisite for newer ones (ie. [Feature Update for Windows 21H1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/feature-update-to-windows-10-version-21h1/a6fc8331-afc0-4ea1-a329-2d25c2954274)).

[image: Windows Update trying to install update that's already installed]

[image: Windows Update trying to install update that's already installed]

[image: Windows Update trying to install update that's already installed]

With the image below the date is different.

[image: Windows Update trying to install update that's already installed]

However Reliability Monitor fails to acknowledge any Windows Update for KB505565 installation on the 16th and says it happened on the 23rd.

[image: reliability monitor some windows updates has installed]

Apparently KB4023057 has installed on the following dates, yet I'm being asked to install it again.

- 09/09/2021
- 28/07/2021
- 18/06/2021

Below is what I've already tried

- Running the Windows Update Troubleshooter
- Running the Background Intelligent Transfer Service Troubleshooter (I know it's already built into Windows Update troubleshooter but I ran it independently anyway for good measure)
- Using dism, sfc and chkdsk [(from the tuneup.bat file)](https://www.tenforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/162488-batch-files-use-bsod-debugging.html#post1994120)
- [Reading the Windows Update log](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/67283-read-windows-update-logs-windows-10-a.html) (using powershell to generate the .log file)
- Making sure all my drivers in Device Manager are working and don't have an exclamation mark
- Running [.NET Framework Optimization Service](https://archive.is/vIaDh) or DrainNGenQueue.wsf
- [Running In-Place Upgrade for Windows Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5005322-some-devices-cannot-install-new-updates-after-installing-kb5003214-may-25-2021-and-kb5003690-june-21-2021-66edf7cf-5d3c-401f-bd32-49865343144f)
- Renaming the "Software Distribution" folders using the [instructions on the Microsoft Support website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/troubleshoot-problems-updating-windows-188c2b0f-10a7-d72f-65b8-32d177eb136c)

This is what happens when I install it anyway?

[image: Windows Update trying to install update that's already installed]

Does anyone here have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Already tried the following: Running the Windows Update Troubleshooter
> Running the Background Intelligent Transfer Service Troubleshooter (I
> know it's already built into Windows Update troubleshooter but I ran
> it independently anyway for good measure) Using dism, sfc and chkdsk
> (from the tuneup.bat file)

Now you need to try the Windows 10 Repair Install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

Start with the option to Keep Everything and see if that works (normally does).

If not, there are two more Repair options:  Keep only Data and Keep Nothing. These are more invasive than the first option which leaves you where you started with errors corrected.

Comment: I have a recovery partition. https://i.imgur.com/d7pSbLH.png Should I use the Reset this pc option from my current windows installation or should I use the `.iso` file from the Microsoft website? My version of windows is an OEM version so it came pre-installed with various drivers, software and power plan settings specific to my computer manufacturer. If I use the `.iso` file from the Microsoft website then I'll lose all that OEM installation in favour of a retail installation, and I might then be hindered as I'll be lacking various drivers. https://i.imgur.com/GVoLm7T.png

Comment: You are much better to use the Repair method. Use Keep Nothing if you wish to start fresh, or Keep Data if you wish to keep your Profile.

Comment: To confirm on which route you’re asking me to take, does that mean you want me to use the link you provided to download an `.iso` file to do a “repair install”, or for me to use the recovery options to “reset my computer” under the settings program which will use my recovery partition?

Comment: The Repair Link (provided in my answer) assures that Windows will keep as much as you wish (and that works in your case). Keep Everything, Data or Nothing. The recovery partition may try to just rebuild your computer to factory specs.